# Generate means and std. dev. in a repeated measures ANOVA

Tags: spss, repeated-measures, mean

I got a repeated measures ANOVA with two timepoints (i.e. variables A1 & A2) as within-subjects dependent variable, and variable B as a between-subject independent variable.

In the output (SPSS) I can lookup the means of the variables across levels (under descriptive statistics):

```
       B        Mean    Std. dev.   N
A1     B1       x       x           x
       B2       x       x           x   
       Total    x       x           x       
A2     B1       x       x           x   
       B2       x       x           x   
       Total    x       x           x
```

However, I want to report the means for B1 & B2 for A. Can I just calculate the average of the means and standard deviations of B1 and B2 for A1 and A2? Or is it possible to generate these means and standard deviations (possibly in syntax?)?

With the estimated marginal means I can generate the means of B1 and B2 for A, however I’m not sure it would be similar to the descriptive statistics, because these would be sample means and standard errors instead of means and standard deviations.